# Url routing is not working?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

web.config for url rewrite is

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Mobile Portal">
                <match url="^(code)(/)?([^']*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="Code.aspx?id={R:3}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>


input: www.abc.com/Code.aspx?id=123abcdef
Required output: www.abc.com/code/123abcdef
current output: http://www.abc.com/Code.aspx?id=.aspx
```

The valid page url is **www.abc.com/code/123abc** . I need "123abc" . When I am accessing the page by **www.abc.com/code/123abc**, the url is converted to "**http://www.abc.com/Code.aspx?id=.aspx** ".I am using IIS 7. So how can I fix this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use url routing instead of url rewriting. for this purpose go to Global.asax file and write RegisterRoutes method like this :

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("my_abc_page",
        "code/{id}",
        "~/Code.aspx");
}
```

with above command, any request like `www.abc.com/code/123abcdef` interpret to `www.abc.com/Code.aspx?id=123abcdef` and you can access to this id in code of your page :

```
theId = Page.RouteData.Values["id"] as string;
```